# Get the first elements (take function) of a DStream

Tags: scala, apache-spark, spark-streaming

I look for a way to retrieve the first elements of a DStream created as:

```
val dstream = ssc.textFileStream(args(1)).map(x => x.split(",").map(_.toDouble))
```

Unfortunately, there is no **take** function (as on RDD) on a dstream //**dstream.take(2) !!!**

Could someone has any idea on how to do it ?! thanks

Comment: You can't have `take` as the result wouldn't be a `DStream` as it would no produce further RDDs. But you know the time interval for your `DStream`, so you can calculate the time interval that will generate the next 2 (say). So you can use `slice` - which is also the only method on `DStream` that produces a sequence of RDDs, so it's pretty much your only option?

Comment: Do you care about order of the elements?  There's a way if you *don't*

Comment: It's not clear to me whether you want another `dstream` with `n` elements of the  original `dstream` or only take `n` elements on every iteration and do some operation on them. Could you clarify?

Comment: Sorry for not being so clear ! I want doing the first case (take the first **n** elements of the original **dstream**)

Comment: Hi @TheArchetypalPaul - I have an issue with the slice option. Can you please take a look at this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55257884/creating-a-slice-of-dstream-window

Answer (score 1):

You can use transform method in the DStream object then take n elements of the input RDD and save it to a list, then filter the original RDD to be contained in this list. This will return a new DStream contains n elements.

```
val n = 10
val partOfResult = dstream.transform(rdd => {
  val list = rdd.take(n)
  rdd.filter(list.contains)
})
partOfResult.print
```

Answer (score 1):

The previous suggested solution did not compile for me as the *take()* method returns an Array, which is not serializable thus Spark streaming will fail with a *java.io.NotSerializableException*.

A simple variation on the previous code that worked for me:

```
val n = 10
val partOfResult = dstream.transform(rdd => {
  rdd.filter(rdd.take(n).toList.contains)
})
partOfResult.print
```

Answer (score 0):

Sharing a java based solution that is working for me. The idea is to use a custom function, which can send the top row from a sorted RDD.

```
            someData.transform(
                     rdd ->
                    {

                        JavaRDD<CryptoDto> result = 
                                rdd.keyBy(Recommendations.volumeAsKey)
                        .sortByKey(new CryptoComparator()).values().zipWithIndex()
                        .map(row ->{
                            CryptoDto purchaseCrypto = new CryptoDto();
                            purchaseCrypto.setBuyIndicator(row._2 + 1L);
                            purchaseCrypto.setName(row._1.getName());
                            purchaseCrypto.setVolume(row._1.getVolume());
                            purchaseCrypto.setProfit(row._1.getProfit());
                            purchaseCrypto.setClose(row._1.getClose());
                            return purchaseCrypto;  
                        }
                        ).filter(Recommendations.selectTopinSortedRdd);
                        return result;
                    }).print();
```

The custom function `selectTopinSortedRdd` looks like below:

```
                public static Function<CryptoDto, Boolean> selectTopInSortedRdd = new Function<CryptoDto, Boolean>() {
                    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
                    @Override
                    public Boolean call(CryptoDto value) throws Exception {
                        if (value.getBuyIndicator() == 1L) {
                            System.out.println("Value of buyIndicator :" + value.getBuyIndicator());
                            return true;
                        }
                        else {
                        return false;
                    }
                }
                };
```

It basically compares all incoming elements, and returns `true` only for the first record from the sorted RDD.

Answer (score 0):

This seems to be always an issue with DStreams as well as regular RDDs.

If you don't want (or can't) to use .take() (especially in DStreams) you can think outside the box here and just use reduce instead. That is a valid function for both DStreams as well as RDD's.

Think about it. If you use reduce like this (Python example):

```
.reduce( lambda x, y : x)
```

Then what happens is: For every 2 elements you pass in, always return only the first. So if you have a million elements in your RDD or DStream it will shrink it to one element in the end which is the very first one in your RDD or DStream.

Simple and clean.

However keep in mind that `.reduce()` does not take order into consideration. However you can easily overcome this with a custom function instead.

Example: Let's assume your data looks like this x = (1, [1,2,3]) and y = (2, [1,2]). A tuple x where the 2nd element is a list. If you are sorting by the longest list for example then your code could look like below maybe (adapt as needed):

```
    def your_reduce(x,y):
      
      if len(x[1]) > len(y[1]):
        return x
      else:
        return y 

yourNewRDD = yourOldRDD.reduce(your_reduce)
```

Accordingly you will get '(1, [1,2,3])' as that has the longer list. There you go!

This has caused me some headaches in the past until I finally tried this. Hopefully this helps.