# pyspark - retrieve first element of rdd - top(1) vs. first()

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, rdd

I have to retrieve the element that satisfies the condition 1. from my rdd:

```
[((4, 2), (6, 3), (2, 1)),
((-3, 4), (2, 1)),
((4, 2), (-3, 4)),
((2, 1), (-3, 4)),
((6, 3), (-3, 4)),
((2, 1), (6, 3), (4, 2)),
((-3, 4), (4, 2)),
((4, 2), (2, 1), (6, 3)),
((-3, 4), (6, 3))]
```

The result needs to match

```
[((2,1),(6,3),(4,2))]
```

I thought I could use rdd.top(1) 
or 
    rdd.first(),

as top(n) sorts and then retrieves I will not get to my desired Element with it.

rdd.first() gives me ...

```
[(4, 2), (6, 3), (2, 1)]
```

(A. can you explain the reason for the different results?) Solved.

B. can you help me retrieve the needed result? It needs to be an rdd, the order does not matter. However, the brackets/structure do.

Comment: can you explain more about result. Do you want to match complete String or only part like (2,1) or (6,3) or (4,2)  Means what you actual condition 1 is please explain

Comment: I need to return a rdd that matches with the same content as [((2,1),(6,3),(4,2))]. So, if I understand the structure of rdd correctly, it should be an rdd with one element, which holds the three points (4,2), (6,3) and (2,1) in any order. To be sure I faked the result with "fake = sc.parallelize([((4, 2), (6, 3), (2, 1))])" and then "return fake". It satisfied the Test. So I guess the remaining problem is, how to retrieve the first Element and retain all the brackets...

Comment: what's the required result? Is it an rdd with `[((4, 2), (6, 3), (2, 1)), ((2, 1), (6, 3), (4, 2)), ((4, 2), (2, 1), (6, 3))]`. Also, I'm starting to suspect this is for some course! o.O

Comment: No, it is an rdd like [((4, 2), (6, 3), (2, 1))]. Well, I will use it as a tiny part of an assignment, but it is primarily for my understanding of how to handle rdds properly.

Comment: how about `your_rdd.take(1)`?

Comment: @samkart - That is it! Thank you. I did not consider take() as I thought it would not ensure to use the first. Shame on me! You wanna answer, so I can accept?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I got - You just need the first element from the `RDD`.

This can be achieved using `RDD.take(1)` - But this will return a `list`, and not an `RDD`.

```
RDD.take(1)
# [((2, 1), (4, 2), (6, 3))]
```

However, if you want the first element as an `RDD`, you can `parallelize` it

```
frst_element_rdd = spark.sparkContext.parallelize(RDD.take(1))
```

I haven't seen anything else that does this. So let me know if someone has something better.

Comment: That works perfectly, thank you. I will read more about it and comment if I find alternatives.

Answer (score 0):

Hopefully this helps somebody that was stuck with this for ages. I've answered a related question just earlier here:

[Stack Overflow: Get the first elements (take function) of a DStream](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28697888/get-the-first-elements-take-function-of-a-dstream/65270477#65270477)

The issue is if you need to do further computation you really don't want to use take(). For just values it is fine and valid, but otherwise not great if you want to re-inject the value for example as take() is an Action and you are leaving the RDD 'space'.

In DStream especially you can't use take. Instead try the following simple 'hack' which is 100% valid and much much easier:

In Python: `.reduce( lambda x, y : x)`

So basically: `yourNewRDD = yourOldRDD.reduce( lambda x, y : x)`

What this will do is, it will pass in 2 elements of your RDD every time but only return the first. So any length RDD will shrink into an RDD with just len = 1.

You can still do .take() if you really need the values but if you just want your RDD to be of len 1 to do further computation (without the .take() Action) then this is the better way of doing it.

As I said above. In DStreams you can't do take so this is almost your only option really and it is very fast and simple as well.

**NOTE:** This will not preserver any kind of order. To see how to overcome this see my code example under the link (other question) above.

Good luck!